# With border-collapse separate adding border-spacing changes the height of the rows

Tags: css-tables, css

I have:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

When I add:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 5px 10px;
}
```

I get the effect of separated rows, which I want. But the height (computed height) of each row has increased from 62px to 102px which I don't want.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Yr6Zx/) that shows the calculated heights for the cells in two tables (one with border spacing 0 0 and the other with 5px 10px) but it reports the same value for each.

Comment: As per Mr Lister's comment. Thanks Mr Lister. You proved what i suspected. This is not the normal behaviour. The problem turned out to be something to do with my using a twitter bootstrap row-fluid inside one of the tds. Once I replace that with my own 3 column float system there is no problem. I ran out of time to analyse exactly why. But the div with row-fluid on was getting an increased height with the border-spacing applied.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.